# customizing apache tomcat authentication Required popup

Tags: apache, authentication, tomcat

i want to add a "register" link into the apache authentication popup.
[image]

i would also like to change the error message page that is called when you press cancel.
i looked into directory www/error where i found some files but it seem none of those files is the error page that is called.
how can i find the Authorization Required page that is called ? 
so i can change it.

Comment: If this is native Tomcat/Apache authentication, I don't think message box could be customized. But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - that's native browser behavior, not an Apache popup.   Try different browsers and see how they do the popup differently.

Comment: thanks, is there another way that still uses the .htaccess but is more customizable ?