# customize tomcat's user authentication pop up

Tags: authentication, tomcat, popup, tomcat7

I would like to customize the dialog window that pops up asking users to authenticate. I am using tomcat basic authentication; currently when the user hits a protected page they get a dialog box that says

> A username and password are being requested by http://localhost:8080. The site says: "Authentication required"

I am pretty sure that I read somewhere that it is possible to change this message. Does anybody know how or where?

Comment: I see this might be a dup of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580075/customizing-apache-tomcat-authentication-required-popup 
I reallly thought it was possible to change the message from "Authentication Required" to something else but I guess it might not be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat is using the realm name you can configure in web.xml

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method> BASIC </auth-method>
    <realm-name> Example Basic Authentication </realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

See, for example http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the link; that is where I first saw it but today I skipped right over that key line in the last example. Thank you!